# Global styling issue with angular-cli 1.0 rc 0 , bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am trying to add the bootstrap 4 in my **angular-cli.json** file like below,

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.css",
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ],
```

I Do not get any errors but I am not getting the bootstrap classes available to my component either.  It seems to be an issue with the angular-cli 1.0 rc 0 .

Second issue is, unless I removed the reference of bootstrap 4, as shown above, I do not get the styles from my "styles.css" file either.

has anyone faced this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check the hierarchy of the references

Comment: which references you want me to check...can you please be specific..Thanks

Comment: see if your sources tab in dev tools of broswer has both styles.css and bootstrap css.

Comment: yes, I see styles.bundle.js .   Bootstrap is loaded as well but not as an bundle but in a seperate folder.

Comment: I did the trick and imported bootstrap in the styles.css file like                          
`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`   and removed the bootstrap reference from the **angular-cli.json** file.  It worked now.